# Upscaling an SVG with sharp and splitting into tiles as PNG - how to optimize performance?

Tags: javascript, node.js, svg, sharp

I have a highly detailed SVG (around 100MB) of a world map and I want to scale it up, divide it into tiles (8k res max) and save them as PNGs. The SVG is 1024x1024, I'm doing this process 7 times, each time doubling the resolution.

For this example I'm at level 5, which results in 16 tiles at 8k resolution. It takes around 6 min to generate the tiles and save them to disk with the following script:

```js
const i = 5
const image = sharp(imagePath, { density: 72 * 2 ** i, limitInputPixels: false, unlimited: true })

const { width, height } = await image.metadata()
const chunkCount = Math.ceil(width / maxChunkSize)
const chunkSize = Math.ceil(width / chunkCount)

for (let j = 0; j < chunkCount; j++) {
  for (let k = 0; k < chunkCount; k++) {
    let left = j * chunkSize
    let top = k * chunkSize
    image
      .clone()
      .extract({ left, top, width: chunkSize, height: chunkSize })
      .png({ effort: 1 })
      .toFile(`${destination}/${j}-${k}.png`)
  }
}
```

I tried using node's multithreading API:

```
const workers = []
const maxWorkers = 16
let activeWorkers = 0
const i = 5
const image = sharp(imagePath, { density: 72 * 2 ** i, limitInputPixels: false, unlimited: true })

const { width, height } = await image.metadata()
const chunkCount = Math.ceil(width / maxChunkSize)
const chunkSize = Math.ceil(width / chunkCount)

for (let j = 0; j < chunkCount; j++) {
  for (let k = 0; k < chunkCount; k++) {
    let left = j * chunkSize
    let top = k * chunkSize
    workers.push({
      worker: new Worker('./workers/processChunk.js'),
      data: {
        x: j,
        y: k,
        left,
        top,
        size: chunkSize,
        imagePath,
        scale: 2 ** i,
        destination: `${destination}/chunks`,
      },
    })
  }
}

while (workers.length > 0) {
  if (activeWorkers < maxWorkers) {
    const worker = workers.shift()
    if (worker) {
      activeWorkers++
      worker.worker.postMessage(worker.data)
      worker.worker.on('message', (chunk) => {
        activeWorkers--
      })
    }
  } else {
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 100))
  }
}

// Worker script
// Have to load the image with sharp again, because the Sharp object is not serializable
await sharp(imagePath, { density: 72 * scale, limitInputPixels: false, unlimited: true })
  .extract({ left, top, width: size, height: size })
  .png({ effort: 1 })
  .toFile(`${destination}/${x}-${y}.png`)
```

This cuts the time down to around 4 min. I expected a larger performance gain, but the fact that each worker has to load the SVG and upscale it again slows things down a lot. On scale levels 6 and 7 this takes hours.

With both examples my CPU is chilling at 20-30% usage. I tried with `os.setPriority` but it only helped a little bit. Is there a way to further give the script priority?

I can't load the image only once and pass it to the workers, because it's a Sharp object and it's not serializable. I can't upscale it first and send it, because it will exceed sharp's pixel limit.

What can I do to optimize the process?

Comment: What you can do is load the SVG file into a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) first: `import { open, read } from 'fs/promises'; import { Blob } from 'buffer'; fd = await fs.open(imagePath); buf = await fs.read(fd); blob = new Blob([buf.buffer])`.

Comment: Isn't it easier to convert the SVG to PNG first, then create the tiles with ImageMagick: ``convert -crop 64x64 source.png tile%d.png``